# how to add new item to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new item to my list, I use firebase without user(email,password)

I want to add new items like this:-

```
list
-vdjs43ndjufd87
         "name" : Jak
         "university" : Harvard



list
-vdjs43ndjufd87
          "name" : Jak
          "university" : Harvard
          "age" : 23
```

this code is not working with me:-

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

let post = ["uid": userID,
        "author": username,
        "title": title,
        "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)`h
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
let post = ["uid": userID,
    "author": username,
    "title": title,
    "body": body]  

ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
```